# Where can I find Google Backup Codes?

Tags: google, multi-factor, account-security

I am traveling long term and I don't want to put my SIM card in the phone every month to receive the SMS code when signing-in to Google (I always recieve 10+ other text messages which costs me a lot).

I know you can sign-in using backup codes but I just can't find them anywhere. I checked https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/security thorougly.

Is this option now obsolete? Google's [answer](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538?hl=en) on how to obtain them is definately obsolete.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This seems more like a problem with User Experience than with information security. If you are looking for other authentication methods, this might be a more reasonable question for this site. :)

Answer (score 1):

On the [help page you link to](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538?hl=en) it states to go to https://myaccount.google.com/security/signinoptions/two-step-verification

When I go to that page under "Your second step" there is a section called Backup Codes with a big "Show Codes" button.

Comment: I don't have this section.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom said this is quite a UX problem, but in case this helps, you can also set a "trusted device" maybe your laptop or your mobile to authorize login.

Check the [Sign in faster with 2-Step Verification phone prompts](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7026266?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) on Google Account Help section.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question - i'd argue far better placed as a comment. Its at best a partial workaround - for example it doesn't help if you have access to a machine with internet but cannot network your own devices (not that i'd advise logging into anything you care about from a random machine).